# Instagram - How to follow the user using API in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I would to **follow** any user with the help of my application. Can anybody suggest me what to do ? As I read the **Instagram API** from [here](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#). But not getting proper idea what to do.

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/

Comment: Hey Lithu, means I have to use /relationship with one of "follow/unfollow/block/unblock/approve/deny" option, right ?

Comment: Ohk Thanks your quick response, will check and update you soon :)

Comment: can any one have some sample ? As i tried at here, but not getting any luck.

Comment: @Nirmit if you have tried . post you code here that will help in solving your problem

Comment: I am not getting any idea, how I can follow any user. As API said that we have to pass clientid and action. But how can API to whom I have to follow ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this way :-

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%@/relationship?access_token=%@",<user id>,<access token>];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:1000.0];
    NSString *parameters=@"action=follow";
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Answer (score 1):

**To follow we only need client_id**

First of all create a client_id by registering [**your app on Instagram**](http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/)

and open given Url in webView.

```
        NSString *urlAddress =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=http://appbellfitness.com/&response_type=token&scope=likes+comments+relationships",client_id];

        NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

        [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

        webview.delegate = self;
```

And add WebView delegate to it.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *orignalUrl =[request.URL absoluteString];

    if ([orignalUrl hasPrefix:CALLBACKURL])
    {
        NSArray* parts = [orignalUrl componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];

        request_token = [parts objectAtIndex: 1];

        NSString *myurl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/25025320/relationship?access_token=%@",request_token];

        NSString *action=@"action=follow";

        BsyncTask *task = [[BsyncTask alloc]init];

        [task asynchronousPost:action url:myurl callerName:@"followTask"];//post this as you like

        task.recieveAsyncResponse = self;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**shouldStartLoadWithRequest**
 I check it starts with my redirect Uri then I get the access token by seperating the url on the basis of = sign. and then i post it using my class you can post it as you like and get response.